# Construction of a Cartier divisor from a prime Weil divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian, locally factorial scheme. Then the homomorphism
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{cyc} : \mathrm{Div}(X)\longrightarrow\mathrm{Z}^{1}(X)
\end{equation*}
from Cartier divisors to prime Weil divisors is surjective, [Görtz&Wedhorn, p.307].

[image]

I am not sure with the trivial part of the above proof, namely $\mathrm{cyc}(d(Z)) = Z$. I don't see, why for the generic point $z\in X$ of the prime Weil divisor $Z\subset X$ the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,z}$ is generated by $f_{z}\in\mathcal{O}_{X,z}$.

Comment: Notice that a prime Weil divisor is an integral closed subscheme of codim 1, so if we view the problem locally on an affine open neighbourhood, we can write $Z=V((f))$. Then the ideal $(f)$ is  prime in order to make $Z$ integral, and the genric point $z$ corresponds to $(f)$. Thus $f_{z}$ is an uniformizer in the discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,z}$.